# Mysql query to search data based on comma separated string of ID's

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have two tables product and category table. On my website, I want to filter my product based on categories. So I am passing the categories ids as a query string in the URL. The ID's are passed in the URL as comma separated string.

I need a MySQL query or stored procedure that can search in the product table based on the category ids.

```
Product Table

| ID | Product_name | Categories                   |
| 1  | TV 1         | LED, 32 inch, HD             |
| 2  | TV 2         | OLED, 55 inch, Ultra HD (4K) |
| 3  | TV 3         | LCD , 24 inch, HD            |
| 4  | TV 4         | LED, 55 inch, Full HD        |

Category Table

| ID | Category Name |
| 1  | LED           |
| 2  | OLED          |
| 3  | LCD           |
| 4  | 32 inch       |
| 5  | 55 inch       |
| 6  | 24 inch       |
| 7  | HD            |
| 8  | Full HD       |
| 9  | Ultra HD (4K) |
```

If the filter query string is "1,3,7" the Product table should return below output

```
Product Table

| ID | Product_name | Categories        |
| 1  | TV 1         | LED, 32 inch, HD  |
| 3  | TV 3         | LCD , 24 inch, HD |
```

What query or stored procedure should be in MySQL?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service.  We fix your failed attempt.  Show us that you have researched and tried to self-solve.  You should be using the ids from your Category table in your Product table.

Comment: you to need to normalise the data, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form your current structure will be very hard to use and maintain

Comment: I expect that your query that you attempt to craft - for yourself - will include: `FIND_IN_SET()` https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php , but then that function indicates further normalization could be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution ...

```
select p.* , count(c.id) as cnt_match   
from product as p 
join category_table  c 
where 
      c.id in ( 1,3,7) and 
      instr(replace(replace(concat(',',p.categories,','),' ,',','),', ',','),
            concat(',',c.categorie_name,','))>0
group by p.id,p.product_name,p.categories;
```

And the result is 3 rows , **TV 4**  is a **HD**

```
+------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| id   | product_name | categories            | cnt_match |
+------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|    1 | TV 1         | LED, 32 inch, HD      |         2 |
|    3 | TV 3         | LCD , 24 inch, HD     |         2 |
|    4 | TV 4         | LED, 55 inch, Full HD |         1 |
+------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

**AND** because the data are not clean in the field *categories* , you need to add some **replace**  to remove space before and after coma